# Mechanism to populate the initial values in the database

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

What is the ideal way to populate the initial values in the database?
I am using spring data JPA. Should I create the tables and insert the initial data into it
programmatically when the application starts? or should I make a SQL script file that is supposed to be run manually before the application starts to ensure that the database is all set up correctly?
Which of the above approaches is better, or is there a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Flyway for managing the scripts and bootstrap the data.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_flyway_database.htm